# find out my Redis key expiration timeout TTL? which function I need to used in C#, So I will get TTL in integer

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using the stackexchange redis.extension.core 5.5 
I have used such syntax

```
 _redisCacheClient.Db0.Get<T>(key);
```

Please let me know if you know something.

Answer (score 0):

Redis TTL  command will return number of seconds left for the key to be expired. I'm not aware of stackexchange API but it should allow you to run this command. Check the API for TTL command.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you can use `KeyTimeToLive`. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/Interfaces/IDatabase.cs#L588).